# Pull Random Images From Options Page

Tags: admin, options

Using this code to get my options

```
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_4');
```

Using the options framework from http://www.wptheming.com

I have 8 options set up using the above tag like

```
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_1');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_2');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_3');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_4');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_5');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_6');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_7');
echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_8');
```

I want to display only 4 at a time and have them on random. Anyway to do this?

I should add the entire code looks like this

```
<div class="box"> 
  <img src="<?php echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_image_1'); ?>" />
   <div>
    <div>
      <p><?php echo eh_get_option('eh_slide_text_1'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So it would also need to match the text with the image

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing WordPress-specific about this, just some simple php:

```
// generate an array of numbers
$numbers = range( 1, 8 );

// shuffle the array in random order
shuffle( $numbers );

// use the first 4 values from the randomized array of numbers
echo eh_get_option( 'eh_slide_image_' . $numbers[0] );
echo eh_get_option( 'eh_slide_image_' . $numbers[1] );
echo eh_get_option( 'eh_slide_image_' . $numbers[2] );
echo eh_get_option( 'eh_slide_image_' . $numbers[3] );
```

If you have a lot of markup to repeat, you can output things in a loop:

```
$numbers = range( 1, 8 );
shuffle( $numbers );
for ( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ ) {
    echo eh_get_option( 'eh_slide_image_' . $numbers[$i] );
}
```

Comment: This does not include anything about eh_slide_text

Comment: just copy/paste the line that outputs the image and change `'eh_slide_image_'` to `'eh_slide_text_'`